# loading a file and getting its contents crashes on me

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

```
private class Lytterklasse implements ActionListener{
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "Sudoku Tekstfiler", "txt");
    chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(getParent());
    String filnavn=chooser.getName();
    In innfil=new In(filnavn);
    int type=innfil.inInt();
    int lengdeBoks=innfil.inInt();
    int breddeBoks=innfil.inInt();
    for(int i=0;i<type*type;i++){
      tallene[i]=innfil.nextChar();
    }
  }
}
```

Why does this crash on me? I cant figure it out. Please help!

Comment: Mark your code as code so it's displayed with proper indent/highligting. Additionally, give us details on "crashes" - i.e. an exception/error.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it's not clear, what the `In` class is. Also you're accessing the `tallene` array which is neither declared nor initialized in your code. Maybe a

```
tallene = new char[type*type];
```

before the `for` loop could solve your problem. For a better answer, we would need more details (especially what kind of 'crash' you're experiencing ...)

Comment: Its the 
 String filnavn=chooser.getName();
    In innfil=new In(filnavn);

when I try to set the name of the file as the new in, regardless of the file being in my java-dir, it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Doh, sorry to bother you. Im too tired.

I went straight from the filechooser without setting a File=chooser.getSelectedfile();

sorry :O

Comment: Might want to accept this so no one keeps trying to answer the question.